# Dropping rows if more than half of the values are zeros - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe that looks like:

```
ENSG0001 0, 74, 54,2
ENSG0002  0, 3, 0, 4
ENSG0003 3, 4, 2, 24
```

I want to delete any row if more than half of the values are zero. So something like:

```
ENSG0001 0, 74, 54,2
ENSG0003 3, 4, 2, 24
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

IIUC

```
n=(df.shape[1]-1)//2

df[df.eq(0).sum(1)<n]
Out[589]: 
          1  2   3   4   5
0  ENSG0001  0  74  54   2
2  ENSG0003  3   4   2  24
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`pd.DataFrame.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and Boolean indexing:

```
mask = (df.iloc[:, 1:] == 0).sum(1) >= len(df.columns[1:]) / 2
res = df[~mask]

print(res)

          0  1   2   3   4
0  ENSG0001  0  74  54   2
2  ENSG0003  3   4   2  24
```